# Dancer DBIC Could not load schema_class

Tags: perl, dancer

I have a Dancer app that is working. I am using DBIC for the database.

I want to add some tables to the database, and so I created new files for those. However, now when I restart the app, I get the following errors

```
Error while loading ././bin/app.pl: Could not load schema_class MyApp::Schema at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Dancer/Plugin/DBIC.pm line 42.
Compilation failed in require at ././bin/app.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ././bin/app.pl line 5.
```

When I remove the new files, everything works fine.

Here is my Schema.pm file

```
package MyApp::Schema;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;

1;
```

Where can I get more information about the error and what I did wrong?

Comment: What is on line 42 and the surrounding lines?

Comment: It is the die line in DBIC when it cannot load the schema, you can see it here http://api.metacpan.org/source/IRONCAMEL/Dancer-Plugin-DBIC-0.1505/lib/Dancer/Plugin/DBIC.pm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces`, all new classes will loaded, which explains why the simple existence of the new class files cause an error. If there is a syntax error in your new class files, then loading the schema will die.

You can use `perl -c` on the new class files to ensure they will compile and get a better idea of the problem if they do not.

Comment: Like I said in my question, things work fine until I try to add more classes derived from DBIx::Class::Core in a subdirectory to define new tables. Somehow this causes the error I gave.

Comment: @Craigy - It's difficult to say without being able to look at the code. One easy mistake to make is to add the class files but not add the new classes to `MyApp/Schema.pm`, but the error doesn't match that.

Comment: @Craigy - Do the new class files end in `1;` to ensure they return true on `require`?

Comment: Yes the new files end in `1;`. I put my `Schema.pm` contents in the question. As you can see it is pretty bare-bones. I have added tables to the database before in this same way, and not had this problem.

Comment: Ah! That helped me track down the problem. The issue was I forgot to change the class names of the new classes in the package declarations (because I had copied them from other files) and so there were conflicts. I am still unsure how I could get more detailed error messages for this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Craigy Not really. Perl's exceptions (die or croak statements) leave a lot to be desired, and in this case the error comes from a DBIx::Class module.